# Issues signing into iCloud Macbook Air 2014 - "You can't sign in at this time", "Can't validate" and other messages

Tags: macbook-pro, icloud, keychain

["You can’t sign in at this time" when signing into iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/210037/you-can-t-sign-in-at-this-time-when-signing-into-icloud/439909#439909)

Hi! I am having similar issues to the above post and have tried all the steps listed, so posting a new question at a moderator's suggestion. I am using a Macbook Air early 2014 running Sierra 10.12.6. I was going to take the additional step of upgrading my OS to Catalina (the Big Sur download wasn't working) but it told me it would delete my Microsoft Office, which I need. Does anyone have any ideas for what else I can do? I know my computer and OS are old. Here's what I tried already in summary (each time turning off my computer, waiting 30 seconds, and turning it back on).

For more context, the reason I got into this problem was that I noticed my Notes and Messages on my computer weren't synching with my iPhone. I tried logging out of iCloud on both devices (first logging out of Messages on my iPhone) and I wasn't able to log back in. Before that I had closed all programs and restarted on my Macbook and restarted/soft reset my iPhone. This is affecting all attempts to sign into iCloud on my computer (in iCloud in System Preferences and in my Messages Accounts under Preferences).

-Reset my time/date

-Deleted my keychain

-Deleted my iCloud Accounts folder (note: there was nothing in the folder if that matters)

-Downloaded that certificate mentioned above (note: is there a new one now, April 2022?)

-Created a new iCloud account and tried logging in (read this on a different post [here](https://appletoolbox.com/mac-cant-connect-to-icloud-here-are-7-ways-to-fix-it/#Fix_2_Change_the_Date_and_Time)) but it wouldn't let me log into that either

-Reset NVRAM

Thank you for your help and any ideas. Willing to try anything.

Comment: Did you set up two-factor authentication?

Comment: Yes it's set up. I didn't see a way to turn it off (another post suggested that) without actually deleting my iPhone from my appleid.apple.com account. What would you recommend?

Comment: When you get the 2FA code, type it in at the end of the password for the account when you login & see if that works.

Comment: Ah sorry. For most routine logins I don't have 2FA. I just get prompted when I'm trying to log into appleid.apple.com and some other sites when accessing my account. In System Prefs on my computer when I try to log into icloud, or log into Messages, there is no prompt for 2FA.

Comment: Is there some way to set up what you're talking about?

Comment: I don't see "Apple ID" in System Prefs. It might not be able to set 2FA up on Sierra.

Comment: This post largely resolved my issue, however the messages I sent from my phone in the 5 days that I couldn't from my Macbook aren't loading on my Macbook. Any ideas? Tried logging out of iCloud on my computer again. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253821862?page=1